# Error response from the Facebook API using HTTP POST request with multipart form-data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, multipartform-data, unreal-engine4

I'm using the Facebook Graph API inside an Unreal Engine 4 project. I'm trying to implement the photo upload. The method I'm using is the multipart form data.

Here is the response I'm receiving:

> response={"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type"
> :"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1366046,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Can't
> Read Files","error_user_msg":"Your photos couldn't be uploaded. Photos
> should be less than 4 MB and saved as JPG, PNG, GIF or TIFF
> files.","fbtrace_id":"AaAcYvfdWM/"}}

*ps: The file is less than 4 MB.*

**HTTP request URL**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos…{my user token}
```

**HTTP request format**

> contentType: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------UE4AdvancedFB
>
> ------------UE4AdvancedFB
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="sf.jpg"
>
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
>
> {byte data}
>
> ------------UE4AdvancedFB--

A important thing to notice is that I don't actually have a file here, but only bytes (coming from a game texture).

What should I do if I only want to send bytes but don't actually have a file? (what should be the Content-Disposition filename? And the Content-Type?)

Any thoughts about the error response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is actually right. The problem was the image data sent. The conversion from the game texture to byte data was actually resulting in a size greater than the maximum 4 MB.

Thanks.